# Thinkpad E485 with Ubuntu 19.04 boot hangs on loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.04, thinkpad

I was having some well-known trouble with the Thinkpad not waking from sleep, and after I had to once more cold-restart it, it now doesn't even boot anymore.

On normal boot the system freezes with the purple splash screen and recovery mode (with option `nomodeset` or without) hangs after `Loading initial ramdisk...`.

I also tried booting a Live USB but this also freezes in the same manner. It seems there is no way to enter the system and access the drives to at least get the data on it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?